# Vue.js 2 v2.Vuetify get Value from checkboxes using bitwise AND

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, bitwise-and, vuetify2

I have info about active modules stored in an int rather than in an array and use bitwise AND to show the active ones:

```
<p>Privileges: {{ privileges }}</p>
<v-checkbox 
  v-for="(b,bi) in allModules.sort((x,y) => x.privileges - y.privileges)"
  :label="b.name"
  :input-value="(b.privileges & privileges)!=0"
 >
 </v-checkbox>
```

Not sure if it is the best way to manage, but for showing the data.. it works

Now, I would like to "read" the value of the `checked` `checkboxes`:
for example, if I check only the first 3 `checkboxes` having respectively `b.privileges` of 2,4 and 8 I would like to read in `this.privileges` the value of 14 (or even the `array [2,4,8]` that I can easily summarize)

how can achieve it?

I've prepared a working example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/vue_js/pen/xxmVNRr?editors=1010)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`@change`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-checkbox/#events-change) event to update the `privileges` value when a checkbox is clicked:

```html
<v-checkbox 
  v-for="(b,bi) in allModules"
  :input-value="(b.privileges & privileges) != 0"
  @change="isSet => updatePrivileges(b.privileges, isSet)"
  ...
/>
```

If the privilege is added, do a boolean `or` operation. To remove it, you can do `and` with the negation of the privilege (keep bits not set in the privilege):

```js
updatePrivileges(privilegeBit, isSet){
  this.privileges = isSet 
    ? (this.privileges | privilegeBit) 
    : (this.privileges & ~privilegeBit)
}
```

(`~` is [bitwise not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT))

Here is the updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/bl1rt/pen/mdaEbMz?editors=1010)

Comment: Great!
yes, I tried to use `@change` but I did it in a way that did not work as expected
I saw that the sort function was also a problem..
but I did not know about `isSet`. Thanks a lot!